# Breakout Game: JButton problems

Tags: java, swing, button, timer, jbutton

I am a beginner programmer and I am trying to make a simple 2D game, Breakout.  I have the logic for the game itself working but I am having trouble with getting the buttons to work with the game.  I added a start and pause button to the top of the screen but whenever I pressed one of these buttons, the paddle at the bottom of the screen cannot move.

When I take out the buttons the game runs perfectly.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!  Thank you in advance.

Below is the code for my game.  I only included the Breakout class because this was were I ran into trouoble.

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.util.TimerTask;

public class Breakout extends JPanel implements KeyListener, ActionListener
{
boolean rightPressed;
boolean leftPressed;
boolean upPressed;
boolean downPressed;

boolean inGame;

int width = 1450;
int height = 900;
Timer tm = new Timer(5, this);
int numRows  =5;
int numCols = 8;
int numBricks = 40;

int mouseX;
int mouseY;

Paddle paddle = new Paddle(width/2, height-40);
Ball ball = new Ball();
//BrickArray brick = new BrickArray(numRows, numCols, width/numCols, (height-100)/numRows);
Brick[][] bricks = new Brick[8][5];

JButton start = new JButton("Start");
JButton pause = new JButton("Pause");
JButton reset = new JButton("Reset");
JButton exit = new JButton("Exit");
JButton help = new JButton("Help");

public Breakout()
{
    setDoubleBuffered(true);
    //tm.start();
    addKeyListener(this);
    setFocusable(true);

    add(start); 
    start.addActionListener(new StartAction());     
    add(pause);
    pause.addActionListener(new PauseAction());
    add(reset);
    add(exit);
    add(help);

    ball.setMaxX(width);
    ball.setMaxY(height);
    ball.setWidth(width);
    ball.setHeight(height);     
    ball.setX(width/2); //width/2
    ball.setY(height/2);    //height

    paddle.setMaxX(width-paddle.getWidth());

    int k=0;
    //row 1
    for(int a=0; a<bricks.length; a++)
    {
        bricks[a][0]=new Brick(120,40);
        bricks[a][0].setX(a*180);
        bricks[a][0].setY(50);
        //System.out.println(k + ": " + a*80);
    }

    //row 2
    for(int b=0; b<bricks.length; b++)
    {
        bricks[b][1]=new Brick(120,40);
        bricks[b][1].setX(b*180);
        bricks[b][1].setY(100);
    }

    //row 3
    for(int c=0; c<bricks.length; c++)
    {
        bricks[c][2]=new Brick(120,40);
        bricks[c][2].setX(c*180);
        bricks[c][2].setY(150);
    }

    //row 4
    for(int d=0; d<bricks.length; d++)
    {
        bricks[d][3]=new Brick(120,40);
        bricks[d][3].setX(d*180);
        bricks[d][3].setY(200);
    }

    for(int e=0; e<bricks.length; e++)
    {
        bricks[e][4]=new Brick(120,40);
        bricks[e][4].setX(e*180);
        bricks[e][4].setY(250);
    }

}

public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
{
    tm.setRepeats(true);

    if(rightPressed)
    {
        paddle.setX(paddle.getX()+5);
        //System.out.println("Pressed");    
    }
    if(leftPressed)
        paddle.setX(paddle.getX()-5);
    /*if(upPressed)
        y--;
    if(downPressed)
        y++;*/  

    ball.checkCollision(paddle);        
    for(int i=0; i<bricks.length; i++)
    {
        for(int j=0; j<bricks[i].length; j++)
        {
            if(ball.checkCollision(bricks[i][j]))
            {
                bricks[i][j].destroy();
                //System.out.println(bricks[i][j].isDestroyed());
                numBricks--;
                ball.move();
                repaint();
            }
        }
    }       


    //ball.checkCollision(brick);
    ball.move();        
    repaint();
}

public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e)
{
    int c = e.getKeyCode();
    if(c == KeyEvent.VK_LEFT)
    {
        leftPressed=true;
    }
    /*if(c == KeyEvent.VK_UP)
    {
        upPressed=true;
    }*/
    if(c == KeyEvent.VK_RIGHT)
    {
        rightPressed=true;
        //System.out.println("Pressed");    
    }
    /*if(c == KeyEvent.VK_DOWN)
    {
        downPressed=true;
    }*/

}

public void keyTyped(KeyEvent e)
{
}

public void keyReleased(KeyEvent e)
{
    int c = e.getKeyCode();
    if(c == KeyEvent.VK_LEFT)
    {
        leftPressed=false;
    }
    if(c == KeyEvent.VK_UP)
    {
        upPressed=false;
    }
    if(c == KeyEvent.VK_RIGHT)
    {
        rightPressed=false;
    }
    if(c == KeyEvent.VK_DOWN)
    {
        downPressed=false;
    }
}   

public void paintComponent(Graphics g)
{
    super.paintComponent(g);


    for(int a=0; a<bricks.length; a++)
    {
        g.setColor(Color.RED);
        bricks[a][0].paintComponent(g);
    }
    for(int b=0; b<bricks.length; b++)
    {
        g.setColor(Color.ORANGE);
        bricks[b][1].paintComponent(g);
    }
    for(int c=0; c<bricks.length; c++)
    {
        g.setColor(Color.YELLOW);
        bricks[c][2].paintComponent(g);
    }
    for(int d=0; d<bricks.length; d++)
    {
        g.setColor(Color.GREEN);
        bricks[d][3].paintComponent(g);
    }   
    for(int e=0; e<bricks.length; e++)
    {
        g.setColor(Color.BLUE);
        bricks[e][4].paintComponent(g);
    }       
    ball.paintComponent(g);
    paddle.paintComponent(g);
    g.setColor(Color.BLACK);
    g.drawString("Bricks left: " + numBricks, 10, 10);

}

public static void main(String[] args)
{
    Breakout obj = new Breakout();
    JFrame jf = new JFrame();
    jf.setTitle("Breakout");
    jf.setSize(1450,900);
    jf.setVisible(true);
    jf.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    jf.add(obj);
}

class StartAction implements ActionListener
{
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
    {
        tm.start();
        System.out.println("Start");
    }
}

class PauseAction implements ActionListener
{
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
    {
        tm.stop();
        System.out.println("Pause");
    }
}
}
```

Comment: When I try to compile that I get 11 compilation errors for `Paddle`, `Ball` & `Brick`, which are all missing.  For better help sooner, post a [Minimal Complete Tested and Readable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) (MCTRE).

Comment: @Andrew Thompson hmmm one week "out of office" and from MCVE is there MCTRE. I'm voting returns back to SSCCE

Comment: @mKorbel  For better or worse, we'll soon be stuck with the community edited MCVE/MCTRE.  The unfortunate fact is that the free host of my 4 internet domains has decided to stop offering web hosting altogether, and most of the domains are not worth paying for hosting.  That means that SSCCE.org will disappear forever at the end of February.. :(

Comment: @Andrew Thompson sure this is/was your decision, my view too hot heads here, please to ignore them, by default I'm using SSCCE/MCVE in my comments, and now I'm don't want to use new model created by perverse bureaucracy on SO,

Comment: @mKorbel *"please to ignore them"*  (chuckle) I find that hard to do when I keep getting hauled over to Meta for a 'good long talking to'.  I figure if I post on SO, I have to just use it the best I can, given the community driven nature of it.

Answer (score 0):

I don't have the other classes implemented so I cannot confirm if this will work.

```
start.setFocusable(false);
pause.setFocusable(false);
```

Alternatively

```
start.addKeyListener(this);
pause.addKeyListener(this);
```